# Ubuntu 18.04 won't recognize Wifi 6 AX201 and NVIDIA 3050ti ( MSI Katana GF66 12UD-074IT )

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, iwlwifi

Good evening everyone.
Two days ago my new Laptop MSI Katana GF66 12UD-074IT has been delivered.

**Specification**: I cannot install more recent versions of Ubuntu since I have a specific project that runs on ROS Melodic and need the 18.04.

I'm having two issues:

- Can't get my NVIDIA 3050ti recognized, tried to solve it by installing Cuda from NVIDIA (which is supposed to installing NVIDIA drivers but apparently didn't solve the issue for me)
- Can't get my WIFI 6 AX201 recognized, ordered a wifi usb stick which gets delivered tomorrow but having the issues solved will surely help.

Hope someone can help me solve the issue, thanks.

Comment: Try the Hardware Enablement packages (hwe linux-generic-hwe...) for getting the latest kernel available.  Also check that you have the latest firmware, even new machines may need updates periocically.

Comment: The better solution is obviously installing an Ubuntu release contemporary to the hardware (instead of 18.04 which has less than a years of support left) and port your "specific project" to the current ROS version.

Comment: I am sure someone can solve those issues, but probably will not, unless you can hire then and pay a reasonable amount of money. People with newer hardware are expected to install newer software.

Comment: Of course paying an expert to solve the issue will be my ‘last chance’ in order to trying to solve it. Unfortunately I am not able, as already mentioned, to upgrade to 22.04 since my professor has specifically asked for 18.04 which  makes things complicated..

Comment: You've given no clues as to what 18.04 system you installed; which kernel stack you've tried? (*was it GA? HWE or though unlikely an OEM option*). Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is the 2018-April release; so will only know about hardware that existed prior to it's release (*actually it's various freezes which were earlier*) with the latest HWE stack from 2020-April, but you didn't provide details of your product/install-media thus haven't given any clues as to your chosen stack (*the ISO used dictates the default kernel stack though one installer allows you to select at install time*)

Comment: I am sorry but I am very new to Linux, I've just downloaded the ISO from Ubuntu and the kernel is 5.4 which is supposed to support at least WI-FI AX201 when installing the respective Intel Driver (5.2+)

Comment: For whatever reasons your professor demands Ubuntu 18.4 - your hardware is too new for the hardware stack. You might buy yourself an used thinkpad to achive a solution or talk to your "professor"